# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to generate Allure Report

Tags: java, gradle, testng, allure

When I run the command-line report tool, it creates the directory but its empty. the allure-results directory has a valid test in it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ns2:test-suite start="1437677969696" stop="1437678045553"
 version="1.4.15" xmlns:ns2="urn:model.allure.qatools.yandex.ru">
```

This is the header file from that test, which looks to be found.

I run the below command line, and it fails with the NullPointerException. I have tried Java 1.7 and 1.8. I am not sure why it finds the files but cannot convert them.

```
build ctaylor$ allure --debug generate -v 1.4.15  allure-results
Generating report for Allure version [1.4.15]
Processing result pattern [allure-results]
Found results directory [/Users/ctaylor/Documents/GitRepo/commerce/lw-testkit/app/build/allure-results]
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My Allure-CLI Version is 2.3 installed via Brew on MAC OSX

I am using IntelliJ Idea with Java, TestNG and Gradle and following the example from the Example projects on Allure's GitHub Repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be mainly caused by connectivity problems to Maven Central Repository. CLI tries to download Allure library version specified in CLI arguments from the Internet. If you're using proxies be sure to [specify settings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) in **~/.m2/settings.xml** file. The following [issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli/issues/35) can clarify things.

Comment: That was it was pointing to my local artifactory once I removed it I was able to get a clearer error and resolve it.